# Can I directly contact another player in clash of clans?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have a friend who is frequently depressed and about a week ago he left the clan. He doesn’t have any other form of contact, and yeah it’s weird, but I’ve already tried everything in my power. I’m really worried and he has seemingly gone inactive with no warning. Please help me and if I can send him an email somehow that would help me so greatly. Please, he needs help and so do I. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can by messaging them the link via email or text. Then you have to friend them.

> Clash Of Clans